# Ubuntu 20.04 on vmware ESXi 7 and Nvidia 2080 ti - device available,drivers installed,external monitor not detected,gpu can't be fully used

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, virtualization, wayland

I have esxi 7 installed and I have passed through my Nvidia RTX 2080 ti to the guest. On the guest side, I have installed ubuntu desktop 20.04 with Plasma and Wayland with the support for Nvidia,following this tutorial :

https://community.kde.org/Plasma/Wayland/Nvidia

lspci shows me that the nvidia graphic card has been detected and passed through and it is using a manually installed driver.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Infact I have installed at first the ubuntu nvidia driver,later the proprietary driver. However,if I want to render a scene with blender using the 2080 ti I can't do it because it said that it can't find a compatible gpu for path tracing.

[image]

Also,ubuntu detects only one monitor,the monitor attached to the esxi default virtual graphic card (that I'm not able to disable,infact on the monitor panel I see that it is enabled only the vmware virtual monitor),but the rtx 2080 is attached to another monitor,that it is not detected.

[image]

but on the driver panel it says that the VMware vga adapter is not working). The same happens with Gnome with wayland enabled. I have passed through also the Intel graphic card and this time it works. I can see the external monitor activated and that it is using that card as primary. I suspect that the nvidia driver does not like wayland for some reason. What do u think ? But esxi likes it,infact when I pass the intel internal card I can activate the external monitor only if I enable Wayland. Is there a way to force the nvidia driver to work great with wayland ? thanks.